# Backend for H2o Deepwater on Ubuntu 16.04 with Radeon Rx Vega GPUs

Tags: h2o

How do I set up a backend for Deepwater (h2o) on Ubuntu 16.04? The GPUs I am using are AMD Radeon RX Vega. Anyone experienced in this topic? Do you need further information? Most explanations and procedures described here and elsewhere seem to refer to NVIDIA cards.

Answer (score 1):

Deep Water is a legacy project (as of December 2017), which means that it is no longer under active development. The H2O.ai team has no current plans to add new features, however, contributions from the community (in the form of pull requests) are welcome.

Having said that, Deepwater was never built for AMD because we used Tensorflow and MXNet as backends and they did not support AMD.